# SharePoint REST _api DateTimeRange query

Tags: javascript, rest, api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a list with start dates and end dates columns with the data type `DateTime`. I want to construct a query that fetches all events that have the start date `or` the end date within the query date range. The problem is that the query uses `and`. So I only get events with start and end dates within the date range query. I tried replacing the `and` with `or` but I only get `Unexpected token` in the console. I looked at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests). But could not solve it. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
        var DateRAngeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDT00';

        var ThreeMonthsEarlier = moment().add(-3, 'months').format(DateRAngeFormat),
            ThreeMonthsFromNow = moment().add(3, 'months').format(DateRAngeFormat);

        var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Program')/items?$select=Title%2CKontaktperson%2CBokning_x0020_till%2CBokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n%2CMax_x0020_antal_x0020_platser%2CID&$filter=Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n%20ge%20datetime'${ThreeMonthsEarlier}%3A00%3A00'%20and%20Bokning_x0020_till%20le%20datetime'${ThreeMonthsFromNow}%3A00%3A00'`;
```

`EDIT`

I made a query using CAML query (serverside code) and I get the result I want. so my guess is that it is possible using the REST _api, I just have to figure out how.

```
 var q = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Or><Gt><FieldRef Name='Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-10-03T00:28:05Z</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name='Bokning_x0020_till' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2010-04-02T00:28:08Z</Value></Lt></Or></Where></Query></View>"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some issue with formatting.

You need to use `$filter=(Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n ge datetime'2017-10-03T00:28:05Z') and (Bokning_x0020_till le datetime'2010-04-02T00:28:08Z')`

So, your url would be:

```
var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Program')/items?
$filter=(Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n ge datetime'2017-10-03T00:28:05Z') and (Bokning_x0020_till le datetime'2010-04-02T00:28:08Z')
$select=Title,Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n,Bokning_x0020_till,Kontaktperson,Max_x0020_antal_x0020_platser;
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. The tool [link](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104051159?tab=Overview) I use to build query strings formats the string a bit differently than your query string. Do you have any links I can visit so I can learn how to build the query your way?